# Como editar um valor do banco de dados utilizando JSF?

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou tentando editar um registro do banco de dados utilizando JSF. A lógica é simples, existe uma lista de clientes, e ao pressionar o botão editar na frente de cada cliente da lista, abre-se um form, com inputTexts carregadas com os valores atuais, e ao editar o texto e pressionar o botão salvar, o JPA lança um comando update na tabela de clientes. Pois bem, mas ao utilizar o código abaixo para realizar tal tarefa, o os componentes inputText não são carregados com os valores atuais dos clientes. Por quê?

**Código da página XHTML:**

```
<p:panel header="Todos os clientes">
            <p:dataTable id="clientes" value="#{clienteMB.clientes}" var="item">
                <p:column headerText="CNPJ" style="text-align: center">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{item.cnpj}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Razão Social" style="text-align: center">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{item.razao_social}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                     <p:commandButton image="images/edit_icon.png" action="#{clienteMB.editarCliente(item.cnpj)}" onclick="PF('new_cliente').show()"
                     title="#{item.cnpj}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                     <p:commandButton image="images/remove_icon.png" action="#" onclick="PF('new_cliente').show()"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                     <p:commandButton image="images/log_icon.png" action="#" onclick="PF('new_cliente').show()"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>

        </p:panel>       
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog header="Pronto" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">
            <h:outputText value="Cliente salvo com sucesso." />
    </p:dialog>  

    <p:dialog header="Editar Cliente" widgetVar="new_cliente" modal="true" height="100">
            <h:form>
                <h:outputText value="CNPJ:" />
                <h:inputText id="cnpj_novo" value="#{clienteMB.alt.cnpj}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Razão Social:" />
                <h:inputText id="razao_nova" value="#{clienteMB.alt.razao_social}"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{editClienteMB.editarCliente}" process="@form"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Excluir"/>
            </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

**Código do ManagedBean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClienteMB {
    Cliente cliente;
    Cliente alt;
    String nova_razao;
    String result;
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;
    HibernateUtil util = new HibernateUtil();
    HttpService http = new HttpService();


    public ClienteMB() throws Exception{
        cliente = new Cliente();
        alt.setRazao_social("A");
        clientes = http.getClientes();
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public String getResult(){
        return result;
    }


    public ArrayList<Cliente> getClientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public void setClientes(ArrayList<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }

    public Cliente getAlt() {
        return alt;
    }

    public void setAlt(Cliente alt) {
        this.alt = alt;
    }

    public void Salvar() throws Exception{

        try{
            util.manager.getTransaction().begin();

            util.manager.persist(this.cliente);

            util.manager.getTransaction().commit();

            util.manager.close();

            result = "Cliente salvo com sucesso";

        }catch(Exception e){
            result = e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    public void editarCliente(String cnpj){
        alt = util.manager.find(Cliente.class, cnpj);
        System.out.println(alt.getRazao_social());
    }

}
```

Comment: Coloque um ID no seu dialog, e no botão editar insira o update com tal ID.

Comment: Após o restart do seu servidor de aplicação (ex: Tomcat), os dados são mostrados corretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde, eu também estava tendo o mesmo problema, e resolvi da seguinte maneira: coloquei o `update` referenciando o `dialog` e troquei o `onclick` pelo `oncomplete`. Segue o trechinho `html` com as respectivas mudanças

```
update=":#{p:component('idDialog')}" oncomplete="PF('new_cliente').show()"
```

Answer (score 0):

É desnecessário buscar o cliente no banco ao selecionar, altere o seu método de seleção de cliente passando o cliente selecionado como parâmetro:

```
public void editarCliente(Cliente clienteSelecionado){
    alt = clienteSelecionado;
    System.out.println("cliente " + clienteSelecionado.getRazao_social() + " selecionado!");
}
```

E na tela:

```
            <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                 <p:commandButton image="images/edit_icon.png" actionListener="#{clienteMB.editarCliente(item)}" onclick="PF('new_cliente').show();"
                      title="#{item.cnpj}"/>
            </p:column>
```